# Ubuntu 13.04 update error in terminal window

Tags: software-center

I coudn't update my newly installed ubuntu software. i get error like this

```
matha@matha-HCL-Notebook:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for matha: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no other software accessing the package management files is running. Likely culprits are the **Software Center** or **Synaptic**.

Comment: No sub packages are running currently. how could i solve this issue ? ( thanks for the interest that you took responding me)